# Generate query string with qualifiers

Tags: python, api, rest, python-requests, github-api

Using the [Github API v3](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-code), I can use the following query to get information on any files with the `.gitignore` file extension in the [github/gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore) repo:

```
curl https://api.github.com/search/code\?q\=filename:\*.gitignore+repo:github/gitignore
```

What's the most pythonic way to translate this into python using the requests library? This is what I currently have, but I'm not sure this is the "right" way to do it:

```py
import requests

filename = "*.gitignore"
repo = "github/gitignore"

res = requests.get(
    "https://api.github.com/search/code", 
    params=f"q=filename:{filename}+repo:{repo}",
)
```

Comment: Have you checked the documentation here: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls ? I haven't tried your specific case.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary of your search qualifiers, and then iterate through keys and join them with a space :

```
" ".join([f'{key}:{value}' for (key, value) in query.items()])
```

Example :

```
import requests

query = {
    "filename": "*.gitignore",
    "repo": "github/gitignore"
}

res = requests.get(
    "https://api.github.com/search/code", 
    params = {
        "q": " ".join([f'{key}:{value}' for (key, value) in query.items()])
    }
)

print(res.json())
```

It translates the search value as [`filename:*.gitignore repo:github/gitignore`](https://api.github.com/search/code?q=filename:*.gitignore%20repo:github/gitignore)

Answer (score -1):

This should work

```
import requests
filename = "*.gitignore"
repo = "github/gitignore"
res = requests.get("https://api.github.com/search/code" + f"?q=filename:{filename}+repo:{repo}")
```

Comment: this is a worse alternative than what I already posted (plus it doesn't even work since you forgot to put a ? at the end of the "seach/code")

Comment: Fixed the error. You can also pass a dictionary in params like that: params={'filename': filename, 'repo': repo} 
That looks cleaner

Comment: That doesn't work, that will delimit the arguments with an &